# Can't use Geolocator inside Workmanager's task in Flutter

Tags: flutter, geolocation, flutter-workmanager, geolocator

I am trying to use either `Geolocator.getCurrentLocation` or `Geolocator.checkPermission()` inside Workmanager's task. Both of those calls raise the same exception:
`MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getCurrentPosition on channel flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator)` - for `getCurrentLocation`.

And `MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method checkPermission on channel flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator)` for the `checkPermission` method.

Here is an example of the code

```dart
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((taskName, inputData) async {
    await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
  });
}
```

There are few issues opened in GitHub repo of Geolocator, but there are no answers for them.

- https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-geolocator/issues/1045
- https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-geolocator/issues/1041
- https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-geolocator/issues/1038

Any ideas on how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that with version 3.1.6 of the `geolocator_android` the default method channel implementation has been replaced by a platform specific implementation. However since the task is run in a separate isolate which executes without the Flutter engine, the platform specific implementation (in this case `geolocator_android`) is not registered with the platform interface (`geolocator_platform_interface`) resulting in the `MissingPluginException`.

To use version 3.1.6 or later make sure you register the platform specific implementation when the `executeTask` is run.

```dart
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) async {
   if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
     GeolocatorAndroid.registerWith();
   } else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS || defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.macOS) {
     GeolocatorApple.registerWith();
   } else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.linux) {
     GeolocatorLinux.registerWith();
   }

    await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
  });
}
```

Alternatively if you are running Flutter 2.11+, you can use the new `DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized()` method to ensure all packages are registered correctly:

```dart
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) async {
    DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();

    await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
  });
}
```

More information can be found [here](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-geolocator/issues/1041#issuecomment-1125862107) and [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/98473#issuecomment-1060952450).

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the solution for current problem. All I had to do is to replace the version of `geolocator_android` lib from `^3.1.6` with `3.1.5`.

For some reason version 3.1.6 doesn't work as excepted.

```yaml
geolocator: ^8.2.0
geolocator_android: 3.1.5
```